# Why rsh not opens and reads PAM modules and limits.conf?

Tags: linux, bash, c, pam, rsh

I am working on a project, that uses rsh utility for remote connection.

But my project needs some extra features for that, so I add that features.

Till now, all the things are going fine. But when I take a `strace` on rsh server. It shows that it opens and reads PAM modules and limits.conf.

But the rsh, that I made is not able to open and read PAM module and limits.conf.

I followed [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68405/command-to-trace-rsh-server-to-check-behaviour-of-particular-system-call) to check above things.

Number of calling of PAM module and all these things are exactly same in Standard rsh and mine rsh.

**The reasons that I think, behind this weird behavior** :-

1. May be `configure` file does not load by `makefile` of mine rsh.
2. May be it does not load `MCONFIG` , `MRULES` in makefile.

But I didn't understand how can I confirm my doubt, and remove this problem.

I tried to use GDB debugger, but I am unable to locate where this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

**Never, ever even consider using rsh for remote connections.** It is horribly insecure to have `rshd` running, as it is very easy to take over any account (and even the whole machine) unless utmost care is taken. And as you see, it hasn't been kept up to date either.

Use `ssh`, with shared keys (no password). It isn't much harder to set up, and offers some security.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will take care of the same. But right now, moving to ssh is not possible. Because of some project issues. So please help me to overcome of above problem. My head is banging, I didn't understand from where I can start. Help me please.

Comment: In our days your comment is just wrong! I don't have a single networking machine whose services are directly accessible through their public IPs. Anything but port 22 is always closed to the public. If I want to access such a machine I will route my traffic though an encrypting vpn anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If this is going on the open internet, you should be prepared for a breakin soon after putting it up.  Kiddies scan the net constantly for open ports with old vulnerabilities like this one.   Search google for "rsh exploit" and you get around 100,000 hits.

Your project might have resource issues now, but you might consider adding the expense of cleaning up repeated breakins until rsh is closed.