# How can I add PAM functionality in netkit-rsh-0.17

Tags: linux, centos, pam, rsh, xinetd

I am using CentOS. In my project, that is working on a network, I need an `rsh` utility. I downloaded `netkit-rsh-0.17` for that and until recently all worked fine.

But now I found that this utility does not load *PAM Module*, which is required in my project.

In the `README` file, It says,

```
WARNING: The PAM support in this version may be screwed up. If
you use PAM, please be sure to double- and triple-check the
behavior of rshd, rlogind, and rexecd to make sure they don't
inadvertently grant access when it should be denied. If in doubt,
get the SRPMs from Red Hat and use their sources instead.
```

Then how can I use this utility to solve my above problem.

**I know that rsh should not be used, because of security issue. SSH should be used instead of rsh. But due to project issue, I have to use this only.**

Comment: Did you try to build SRPMs?

Comment: No can you tell me what is that ?

Comment: Source code, patches, and build instructions, all packaged into a single file (SRPM) -- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM